Is this Insertion sort or selection sort?
Confused about insertion sort and selection sort.
I am learning sorting algorithms and I just want to confirm that it is insertion sort.
public class bubbleSort{
    
    //func.
    public static void iSort(int arr[]){
        System.out.println();
        
     for(int i= 1; i<arr.length; i++){
        int current = arr[i];
        if(current>arr[i]){
            current=arr[i];
        }
        for(int j=i-1 ; j>=0 ; j--){
            if(current<arr[j]){
                arr[j+1]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=current;
            }
        }
     
     }
     
     System.out.print("Sorted array: ");
     for(int i=0; i<arr.length ; i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
     }
    }

    //driver code
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.print("Original array: ");
        int arr[] = { 7, 8, 3, 1, 2};
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length ; i++){
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
        iSort(arr);
    }
}


Yes, it is an insertion sort algorithm, and should work fine, but it contains some unnecessary code and could be improved like this:
public class InsertionSort {

    public static void iSort(int arr[]) {
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int current = arr[i];
            int j = i - 1;

            // Shift elements of arr[0..i-1] that are greater than current
            // to one position ahead of their current position
            while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > current) {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                j--;
            }

            arr[j + 1] = current; // Place current in its correct position
        }

        System.out.print("Sorted array: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print("Original array: ");
        int arr[] = { 7, 8, 3, 1, 2 };

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }

        iSort(arr);
    }

}

Essentially, you should remove the first if because is useless and you can avoid some of the inner loop iterations by changing and moving your if condition into a while loop, and assigning the current element outside of it.

the only errors I see in code posted in question is unnecessary code (the first if is doing nothing; the assignment arr[j]=current can be moved to after the inner loop) - have I missed something?

no you're right, I got confused with the assignment in the loop and thought it would cause problems in that way. I will edit the answer and point out that these are only improvements to the original code
